# Problem with Rails page caching and automatic extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, format

I have a `JSON` and `XML` based API that needs to be page cached. I have setup my routes on the api to include the format as part of the URL, such that URL's like this work:

```
http://example.com/foo/1/bar/2/xml
http://example.com/foo/1/bar/2/json
```

The problem I am seeing is that in the server's `public` folder, the files are being saved as `xml.xml` and `json.json`, and this causes cache misses the next time the URL is accessed.

Is there a way to either:

1. Turn off the auto extension generation so that they are saved without an extension at all? (EX: `RAILS_ROOT/public/foo/1/bar/2/json`)
2. Force all the extensions to be `.html` for every call. (EX: `RAILS_ROOT/public/foo/1/bar/2/json.html`)

Either of these would cause my server to return the cached file instead of a miss. How can I do this?

**EDIT:**
Somebody asked for the relevant route:

```
scope '(foo/:foo_id)', :foo_id => /\d+/ do
  get '/bar/:bar_id/:format' => 'bars#show', :bar_id => /\d+/, :format => /json|xml|html/
end
```

**SOLUTION**:
While I was looking for an official way to make this happen using the built in page caching support, I ended up just using an after filter and my own page cache method, as suggested by Anton

```
# application_controller.rb
def cache_api_page
  if REDACTEDServer::Application.config.action_controller.perform_caching
    self.class.cache_page(response.body, request.path, '')
    puts "CACHED PATH: #{request.path}"
  end
end

# bar_controller.rb
 after_filter :cache_api_page, :only => [ :show, :index ]
```

Comment: have you tried the "normal" convention in the API, as of ..bar/2.xml and ../bar/2.json ?

Comment: This is not the API design and I need to make it backwards compatible, so I cannot change to the .ext method. IMHO though, it makes for ugly urls.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

  after_filter(:only => :show, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format.json? }) do |controller|
    controller.class.cache_page(controller.response.body, controller.request.path, '.html')
  end

end
```

When http://example.com/foo/1/bar/2/json is accessed, it will write page to cache (RAILS_ROOT/public/foo/1/bar/2/json.html)

And if you get http://example.com/foo/1/bar/2/json again, you receive RAILS_ROOT/public/foo/1/bar/2/json.html, but your http server(Apache?) should know about content type of this files.

Otherwise content type will set to 'text/html'

**UPDATE**

To you .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\/json$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Content-Type "text/json"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>


<FilesMatch "\/xml$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Content-Type "text/xml"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: This seems like it could work, but requires a lot of code to be written across my app and methods. I will hold off on giving you the answer until I see what else comes in. Regarding Apache, the requests come in exactly like the URL listed above, thus, Apache does not know it is an xml or json file unless i make the requests have a .xml or .json extension. This is why I need to do this.

Comment: Your update wont work on rails because htaccess is ignored with rails, passenger apache setups. Your initial answer is still valid though

Answer (score 0):

In your application.rb configuration block try adding:

```
config.action_controller.page_cache_extension = '.html'
```

It should ignore the extension calculated from the request, and always use this.
You could also try using this with an empty string instead.

**EDIT:** actually this won't work because this only sets a default. If the request has an extension (in your case, concluded from :format) it will be used.

I suggest changing :format in your routes to something else, that rails will not give special meaning to, like :fmt. Then rails should not add the extension and default to '.html'.

**EDIT2:** If you have to use :format you can monkeypatch Rails:

```
ActionController::Caching::Pages::ClassMethods
  private
  def page_cache_file(path)
    name = (path.empty? || path == "/") ? "/index" : URI.unescape(path.chomp('/'))
    name << page_cache_extension #unless (name.split('/').last || name).include? '.'
    return name
  end
end
```

Notice the comment sign I've added before 'unless'. This is the part that overrides the default from my first answer.